# Make menu tab on user profile visible only to profile owner

Tags: permissions, drupal-7, view, hook

I made a "My bookmarks" tab on the user profile page using Views. The tab shows nodes the user has flagged.

However - "My bookmarks" should only be visible on the user's *own* profile page and at the moment the "My bookmarks" tab is visible on every profile a user visits. How do I check whether the current user matches the profile being viewed? I tried that from the View interface, but the access permissions don't have any options that work.

EDIT:

I think it is this code, but I still need some guidelines as to how to implement that:

```
<?php
global $user;
if (arg(0) == 'user' && $user->uid == arg(1)){
  return TRUE;
}
else {
  return FALSE;
}
?>
```

I also found this module, I think it helps a lot [Views Access Callback](https://drupal.org/project/views_access_callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the code and module from above.

The custom module contains this code

```
<?php

 function MYMODULE_views_access_callbacks() {
  return array(
    'MYCALLBACK_user_has_access' => t('User can only see tab on his own profile'));
}

function MYCALLBACK_user_has_access() {
  global $user;
  if (arg(0) == 'user' && $user->uid == arg(1)){
    return TRUE;
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}

?>
```

The Views Access Callback module adds your callback to the Views interface and from there, you can use it for your own view.